# Flutter logs using flogs -where it will be saved

Tags: flutter, logging

Flog plugin for flutter will save logs to database..

https://medium.com/flutter-community/logging-in-flutter-a583b3668228

which database it will be saved,where the configuration is specified and in which directory we can see the log text files once the app is in production?
Pleas help

Answer (score 3):

It will be saved in a text file. {path-based-on-OS}/FLogs/flog.txt.

You can find the details in the source code of the library: 
https://github.com/zubairehman/Flogs/blob/master/lib/utils/storage/logs_storage.dart